# .htaccess gives recursion error on everything

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect all traffic through index.php.

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?ref=$1 [NC,L]
```

I'm always getting HTTP 500 errors, and I check the error.log and I see that its the internal recursion error.  Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not entirely sure whether this is the canonical way to do this, but adding a condition like this will work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?ref=$1 [QSA]
```

(The QSA to add any query strings.)

However, I would recommend an additional

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

to prevent static resources from being sent through your index.php (unless that is *really* what you want.)

Comment: +1, `!-f` & `!-d` ar among _my_ standard 'start of a project' htaccess vocabulary, whether it's really _canonical_ I'm not qualified to say. It does alleviate the problem of matching from Apache to PHP, which has way more & easy tools to try to match an url to a resource then .htaccess files have. The only drawback is you become responable for the 'not found' and other errors, be sure to send those status codes if appropriate.